# Break Group Footer only if the next Group Footer breaks as well

Tags: jasper-reports

I am building a Jasper Report and i came across what i thought was an unexpected outcome. My Report has a fairly large detail band fitted inside a group header and a group footer. The group footer is also fairly big, but it can also shrink a lot, if certain elements are not printed due to their `printWhenExpression` getting evaluated to `false`.

If that happens but the **regular size** of the group footer would have caused the band to break on to the next page the group is **still** printed on the next page.

I found this issue report regarding an explanation on the behavior:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/5709

The solution given is to divide large bands into multiple bands. My problem then is, that i need to keep the band contents on the same page and not have one of the bands break to the next one. If one of the group footer bands needs to break to the next page all group footer bands should break as well.

***Is there a way to specify that bands can only break together?***

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 6.1.1, we introduced the possibility that frame elements could be made smaller than their content.

In your case, you could try take the whole content of your large band and isolate it into a frame, for which you can then set a smaller height, provided that the frame will grow at runtime to accommodate all its rendering content.

This way the band will grow as necessary instead of shrinking due to internal content collapsing.